# How to avoid if/else when using multple suppliers?

Tags: java, design-patterns, if-statement

Is there a way to avoid using if/else statements when data can queried from multiple locations and should be returned on first non null instance?

I'm trying to load preferences for a user from 3 different locations (user preferences, group preferences and system preferences). For example:

```
Preference getPreference(User user, Preference.Type type) {

    Preference preference = getUserPreferenceFor(user, type);
    if (preference != null) {
        return preference;
    }

    preference = getGroupPreferenceFor(user, type);
    if (preference != null) {
        return preference;
    }

    return getSystemPreferenceFor(user, type);
}
```

I would like to avoid using these if checks and chain these methods together so that behavior would remain same but code wouldn't have this ugly duplication.

I have thought of few solutions but non of these strike as elegant one. For example, one way would be to to have each of these methods to the provide the default itself but that would just scatter the if statements.

```
Preference getPreference(User user, Preference.Type type) {
    Preference preference = getUserPreferenceFor(user, type);
    if (preference != null) {
        return preference;
    }

    return getGroupPreferenceFor(user, type);
}

Preference preference getGroupPreferenceFor( 
    if (preference != null) {
        return preference;
    }

    return getSystemPreferenceFor(user, type);
}
```

Another way would be to use some provider interface, create subclasses for each and iterate over providers until first non null is found.

```
public interface PreferenceProvider {
    Preference getPreference(User user, Preference.Type type);
}

public class UserPreferenceProvider implements PreferenceProvider {
    public Preference getPreference(User user, Preference.Type type) {
        ...
    }
}
... group and system provider the same way

final static PreferenceProvider[] providers = new PreferenceProvider[] {
    new UserPreferenceProvider(),
    new GroupPreferenceProvider(),
    new SystemPreferenceProvider()
};

Preference getPreference(User user, Preference.Type type) {
    Preference preference = null;
    for (PreferenceProvider provider : providers) {
        preference = provider.getUserPreferenceFor(user, type);
        if (preference != null) {
            return preference;
        }
    }
}
```

The last one is close enough but it still has this null check (which I'd like to avoid) and I'm pretty confident there's some design pattern which solves this problem. I just can't remember which one ...

Comment: You're basically trying to overcome that Java's methods are not first-class objects; I'd recommend the simplest of the forms for readability instead (i.e. alfasin's answer)

Comment: Depending on java's ability to pass delegate as parameters, (in C#, you can), you can make a generic null-check function and eliminate most of the ifs.

Comment: Why avoid if's just to add so many lines of code? What has value has it brought to the code base?

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
Preference getPreference(User user, Preference.Type type) {

    Preference preference = getUserPreferenceFor(user, type);
    if (preference == null) {
        preference = getGroupPreferenceFor(user, type);
        if (preference == null) {
           preference = getSystemPreferenceFor(user, type);
        }
    }
    return preference;
}
```

It still uses `if`s but looks elegant enough to me.

Comment: +1 for removing the return statement from the middle of the method.

Comment: @Kalaji yeps, that's tip #1 on my list: http://alfasin.com/20-tips-for-becoming-a-better-programmer/ ;)

Comment: the last `if` statement should have `==` instead of `!=`

Comment: Guys, just added a solution with ternary operation. Let me know, if thats a good route? Suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @alfasin not a bad solutions, however it doesn't scale very well. Suppose I have 5+ sources for preferences ... it would become  indentation hell very fast. But thanks for Your input.

Comment: @Ragnar if you have 5+ sources for preferences I'd say that something's wrong with the design ;)

Comment: @Ragnar does it realy needs to scale very well? Every new abstraction is making code harder, not easier, to understand. Sometimes simple `if else` is the best that you can write.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a try using delegations (note: many people said that delegation has performance impact, but you need to measure it yourself to find the truth). Please note it may not compile since it is already long since last I used java.

```
public interface PreferenceGetter{
    Preference get();
}

public Preference getPreferenceIfNull(Preference pref, PreferenceGetter func) {
    if(pref == null){
        return func.get();
    }
    else{
        return pref;
    }
}

public Preference getPreference(User user, Preference.Type type){
    Preference preference = getUserPreferenceFor(user, type);
    preference = getPreferenceIfNull(preference, new PreferenceGetter(){
            public Preference get(){
                getGroupPreferenceFor(user, type);
            }
        });
    preference = getPreferenceIfNull(preference, new PreferenceGetter(){
            public Preference get(){
                getSystemPreferenceFor(user, type);
            }
        });
    return preference
}
```

**Update:**

There is an alternative using `Decorator` pattern instead of delegation (as suggested by ArtemStorozhuk). It is better to use delegation instead of `Decorator` in C#, due to ability of parameter passing, but maybe it's different in java. Moreover, `Decorator` is harder to understand.

```
public interface PreferenceGetter{
    Preference get(Preference pref, PreferenceGetter func);
}

public class NullPreferenceGetter implements PreferenceGetter{
    public Preference get(Preference pref, PreferenceGetter func){
        return null;
    }
}

public class UserPreferenceGetter implements PreferenceGetter{
    public UserPreferenceGetter(PreferenceGetter decorated){
         this.decorated = decorated;
    }
    private PreferenceGetter decorated;
    public Preference get(Preference pref, PreferenceGetter func){
        Preference result = getUserPreferenceFor(user, type);
        if(result == null){
            result = decorated.get(pref, func);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class GroupPreferenceGetter implements PreferenceGetter{
    public GroupPreferenceGetter(PreferenceGetter decorated){
         this.decorated = decorated;
    }
    private PreferenceGetter decorated;
    public Preference get(Preference pref, PreferenceGetter func){
        Preference result = getGroupPreferenceFor(user, type);
        if(result == null){
            result = decorated.get(pref, func);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public Preference getPreference(User user, Preference.Type type){
    PreferenceGetter getter = new UserPreferenceGetter(
        new GroupPreferenceGetter(
            new SystemPreferenceGetter(
                new NullPreferenceGetter())
            )
        );
    return getter.get(user, type);
}
```

Comment: This might actually work ... and I don't mind spending few nanoseconds on the empty function calls. I wonder if this could be chained together like this `Suppiler.of(Preference.class).from(new UserPreference()).or(new GroupPreference()).or(new SystemPreference()).get()`

Comment: In C# it is possible due to extension. The name is `Monad`, don't know the equivalent in java. It is not recommended. It is one liner and if exception thrown, it refer to that one line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with your second idea with the different `Provider` implementations, but add a second method to each `Provider` which can be used to find out if it can provide a value. You can then use that method instead of checking for a null return value, like this:

```
for (PreferenceProvider provider : providers) {
    if (provider.canProvideAPreferenceFor(user, type)) {
        return provider.getUserPreferenceFor(user, type);
    }
}

return null;
```

Comment: I suppose I've should have cleared it in my question that these preferences could come from database, web service etc. This wouldn't be very optimal for stateless service since I'd have to fetch it twice or cache the initial fetch.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. It might be starting to be too much work, but you could create a new set of `Providers` for each use, and calling `canProvideAPreferenceFor` could cache the value inside the `Provider`, return true if it's non-null and return it from `getUserPreferenceFor` when asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Preferences class mutable with a given set of Preferences.

```
Preference getPreference(User user, Preference.Type type) {

    Preference preference = new Preference( getSystemPreferenceFor(user, type) );

    preference.merge( getGroupPreferenceFor(user, type) );
    preference.merge( getUserPreferenceFor(user, type) );

    return preference;
```

}

Now merge will have to check for null, but only in a singular instance. Preference.Preference() can, if suitable, default to getSystemPreference.

This does alter the premise that only one set of preferences will be used.

Comment: I would like to avoid accessing resources if they aren't actually used. This means that I would in most cases get group preferences and the overwrite them with user preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [wrapper (decorator)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern to do this.

You just wrap each check into a single object and then create ready decorated object. Wikipedia has a good example of using it.

Good luck.